# Use of `= default` allowing private constructor to be accessed

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the code:

```
class Key
{
private:
    // If I use the = default keyword here, the line "Key a = {};" compiles
    // If I instead use Key() {}, that same line does not compile (as the constructor is private)
    Key() = default;

    Key(Key const &) = default;
    Key(Key &&) = default;

    Key & operator=(Key const &) = default;
    Key & operator=(Key &&) = default;
};

int main()
{
    // This line compiles when = default is used, but not when an empty constructor is used
    Key a = {};
    return 0;
}
```

What, specifically, is the difference between the default constructor and the empty constructor in this specific instance? Also, I would like for this to NOT compile, is explicitly writing my own empty constructor the only way to do so here? Note: This was tested with both GCC 8.3 and Clang 10.0 with identical results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When default constructor is `default`ed, pre C++20, this code compiles, as your class with defaulted constructor is an [aggregate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), and you can initialize aggregates through aggregate initialization

```
Key a = {}; // interpreted as aggregate initialization and bypasses access qualifier on constructor
```

This code would not compile in C++20 or above, as defaulted constructor makes it non-aggregate:

```
Key a = {}; // interpreted as calling a constructor, since Key is no longer an aggregate.
```

In this case compiler tries to actually call the constructor, and can't, since constructor is private.

When you have

```
Key() { };
```

Your class is no longer an aggregate in any C++ dialect, since it has a user-defined, non-defaulted constructor.

Comment: [This article](https://dfrib.github.io/the-fickle-aggregate/) goes through, in detail, the _fickle aggregate_ throughout C++11 to C++20.